# Adding Cannon.js Body to Three.js Mesh causing Vec3 error with groups and multiple shapes

Tags: javascript, three.js, cannon.js

Basically I've created a group of 2 meshes in Three.js and a Body containing 2 Shapes in Cannon.

Separately they appear fine but when I copy the Body position to the meshes to add physics the code breaks, nothing appears on screen and when logging the positions, for the Body everythings ok but the mesh its showing as undefined.

(The end goal is to replace the mesh with the model)

Any help would be great, heres the code in question:

```
import './style.css'
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js'
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'
import { DRACOLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/DRACOLoader.js'
import * as dat from 'lil-gui'

import * as CANNON from 'cannon-es'

/**
 * Base
 */
// Debug
const gui = new dat.GUI()

// Canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas.webgl')

// Scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene()

/**
 * Models
 */
const dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader()
dracoLoader.setDecoderPath('/draco/')

const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader()
gltfLoader.setDRACOLoader(dracoLoader)

let mixer = null

let gunModel = null

gltfLoader.load(
    '/models/hamburger.glb',
    (gltf) =>
    {
        gltf.scene.position.set(0, 4, 0)
        gunModel = gltf.scene
        scene.add(gunModel)
        console.log(gunModel.position)
    }
)

/**
 * test wireframe cubes
 */
const YGeo = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(2, 6, 2);
const YMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 'green',
    wireframe: true
})
const gun = new THREE.Group();

const blockY = new THREE.Mesh(YGeo, YMat);
blockY.position.x = 4;

const XGeo = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(6,2,2);
const XMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 'green',
    wireframe: true
})

const blockX = new THREE.Mesh(XGeo, XMat);
blockX.position.y = 2

gun.add(blockY)
gun.add(blockX)

gui.add(gun.position, 'y', 0, 5, 0.01);
gui.add(gun.position, 'x', -3, 4, 0.01)
gui.add(gun.position, 'z', -3, 3, 0.01)

scene.add(gun)

/**
 * Floor
 */
const floor = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.PlaneGeometry(50, 50),
    new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        color: '#444444',
        metalness: 0,
        roughness: 0.5
    })
)
floor.receiveShadow = true
floor.rotation.x = - Math.PI * 0.5
scene.add(floor)

/**
 * Lights
 */
const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.8)
scene.add(ambientLight)

const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.6)
directionalLight.castShadow = true
directionalLight.shadow.mapSize.set(1024, 1024)
directionalLight.shadow.camera.far = 15
directionalLight.shadow.camera.left = - 7
directionalLight.shadow.camera.top = 7
directionalLight.shadow.camera.right = 7
directionalLight.shadow.camera.bottom = - 7
directionalLight.position.set(5, 5, 5)
scene.add(directionalLight)

/**
 * Sizes
 */
const sizes = {
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
}

window.addEventListener('resize', () =>
{
    // Update sizes
    sizes.width = window.innerWidth
    sizes.height = window.innerHeight

    // Update camera
    camera.aspect = sizes.width / sizes.height
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix()

    // Update renderer
    renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)
    renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
})

/**
 * Camera
 */
// Base camera
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, sizes.width / sizes.height, 0.1, 100)
camera.position.set(- 8, 4, 8)
scene.add(camera)

// Controls
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas)
controls.target.set(0, 1, 0)
controls.enableDamping = true

/**
 * Renderer
 */
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: canvas
})
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap
renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)
renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))

/**
 * Physics
 */
 const world = new CANNON.World({
    gravity: new CANNON.Vec3(0, -9.81, 0)
});

const floorBody = new CANNON.Body({
    shape: new CANNON.Plane(),
    mass: 0
})
world.addBody(floorBody)

const shapeY = new CANNON.Box(new CANNON.Vec3(1,3,1))
const shapeX = new CANNON.Box(new CANNON.Vec3(3,1,1))

const boxBody = new CANNON.Body({
    mass: 1
})
boxBody.addShape(shapeY, new CANNON.Vec3(3, 0, 0), new CANNON.Quaternion())
boxBody.addShape(shapeX, new CANNON.Vec3(0,2,0), new CANNON.Quaternion())
world.addBody(boxBody)

boxBody.position.set(-0.56, 4.13, -0.02)

console.log(boxBody.position)

gui.add(boxBody.position, 'y', 0, 10, 0.01);

/**
 * Animate
 */
const clock = new THREE.Clock()
let previousTime = 0

const tick = () =>
{

    const elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime()
    const deltaTime = elapsedTime - previousTime
    previousTime = elapsedTime

    world.step(1/60, deltaTime, 3)

    floor.position.copy(floorBody.position);
    floorBody.quaternion.copy(floor.quaternion);

    // if(gunModel) {
    //     gunModel.position.copy(boxBody);
    //     gunModel.quaternion.copy(boxBody)
    //     console.log(gunModel.position)
    // }

    gun.position.copy(boxBody);
    gun.quaternion.copy(boxBody)
    console.log(gun.position.x)

    if(mixer)
    {
        mixer.update(deltaTime)
    }

    // Update controls
    controls.update()

    // Render
    renderer.render(scene, camera)

    // Call tick again on the next frame
    window.requestAnimationFrame(tick)
}

tick()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// access boxBody attributes?
gun.position.copy(boxBody.position);
gun.quaternion.copy(boxBody.quaternion);
console.log(gun.position.x)
```

Comment: Oh my god I cant believe I missed that!